# How to handle hex values in NSAttributedString color

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to use NSAttributedString to get the color attribute from a sample HTML string. Here is how I am trying to create it:

```
func toHTMLAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
    if let data = self.data(using: .unicode),
       let nsAttrString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                                  options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                                                  documentAttributes: nil) {
            return nsAttrString
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Here is the string I am trying this with:

```
<p>My <b> cat </b> has <span style=\"color:#i00008B\">blue</span> eyes.</p>
```

However, the word "blue" is always black. I figured out that this was happening because it is a hex value. How can I convert the hex value to something NSAttributedString knows how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove letter `i`

```
"color:#00008B\
```

and then it's correct e.x for Red

```
let str = """
<p>My <b> cat </b> has <span style=\"color:#ff0000\">blue</span> eyes.</p>
"""
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much.

Comment: That' s an odd shade of blue! <grin>.